# application crash aftet restarting an acticity several times

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have this wierd situation that i can't understand.

I developed an application on android studio, on the first activity i start a second activity, on that second activity i created a SurfaceView child class that extends surfaceView and implemment Runnable and draw on the canvas inside run(), when i exit the thread i call onRestart() to start the canvas thread again.

---

all good so far, i open the thread, draw some images in a loop, exit the thread loop, restart.

**the problem is that after 20 times of restarting, the application crash with no logical reason.**
what do you think the problem can be? how to check it and fix it?

this function is the thread work inside the surfaceView **child** class (of the activity)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!_susspendThread) {
        // draw images
    }
    onRestart();
}
```

this function is on the **parent** activity class

```
protected void onRestart() {
    // make some changes, nothing critical to the question
    // examp. count++;
    surface_view.StartThreadWork();
}
```

another thing i must say although i dont belive it's related to the problem is that onCreate i read some internal files.

thanks for any help.

Comment: If your application is crashing from non-native code, you will get a stack trace in the log.  If you have one, post it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory leak, and this could be from many things.  A good place to begin, is to use the onDestroy() methods of your Activities to cleanup any resources you have generated (like the internal files you are creating in your onCreate method).

Also, there are tons of tools for tracking memory usage, in AndroidStudio (AS) there is a "Memory" tab in the "Android" view.  Also, you can run the "Monitor" tool (available from the command-line, or within AS to get ton's of details on what type of resource you are leaking.